# Throw an error from subprocess to main process without aborting any process

Tags: error-handling, quarkus, kie, kogito

I have a subprocess inside my main bpmn process. What I want to do is when an error occurs on the subprocess, the main process should also error out with the same error.

This is the main process:

[image]

This is the subprocess:

[image]

When any workitem from the subprocess throws an error, if the subprocess is marked as abort parent, the subprocess and the parent processes are aborted (if it is not marked as abort parent, the parent process just continues, or hangs up on "active").

I am working with Quarkus error handlers, in order to have formatted responses for the client that is calling the service. So I need the process to throw an error so I can catch it through the process instance.

If a workitem throws an error directly on the main process everything works as a charm.

**Note**: *the process names were blurred in order to protect private company ideas.*